# Disabling the auto-hiding of scroll bars on Lion

Tags: cocoa

In Mac Lion, the scroll bar hides itself after a few seconds if no activity occurs. I have written an apple script to modify that behavior. I have to turn on the radio button every time my app launches. My question is, I have a cocoa application. Is it possible to keep the scroll enabled for the application always with out having to change the settings in system preferences.I don't want to enable for all the other apps always.  And is the only way via the applescript. Or is there a defaults write to enable the scroll bars in lion ?.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know about a defaults key to set up the style.

When you change the Appearance preference panel's "Show scroll bars", all the [NSScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScrollView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instances are notified and receive a `setScrollerStyle:` with the new style (through the `NSPreferredScrollerStyleDidChangeNotification` notification).

You can achieve the same result by explictly calling `setScrollerStyle:` on the [NSScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScrollView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with the `NSScrollerStyleLegacy` scroller style.

Answer (score 5):

You can write to defaults to accomplish this.

The key is `AppleShowScrollBars` and it has three possible values:

1. `Automatic`
2. `WhenScrolling`
3. `Always`

To set it system-wide from the command line, you could do:

```
defaults write -g AppleShowScrollBars Always
```

It can also be done programmatically by modifying preferences in any of various ways. It can get a little tricky depending on application sandboxing. [This blog post](http://rants.tempura.org/2011/08/01/Altering-OS-X-Lion-Scrollbars.html) explains it in more detail.

Comment: Does anyone know if it is possible to set the scrollbars to NEVER show up using this preference? I never use them, and they frequently prevent me from selecting the last item in a window.

Comment: You mean even when you're scrolling you don't want to see the scrollbar? I don't think you can do that with this preference. I suppose I could add that feature to: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/41429/lionscrollbars

Comment: Yes, all the time. I never want to see them. The problem is that when I scroll to the bottom of a long list, the horizontal scrollbar that appears prevents me from selecting the last item in the list, at the bottom of the window. I have to wait a second for the scrollbars to disappear before I can click.

In any case, I never use the scrollbars -- they just serve as an indicator for how much of the page is invisible. I would love it if you could add that preferencce.

Comment: I agree, this is major flaw in the OSX UI. It literally breaks every application in my toolset.  A good example of this is in Eclipse, when you control hover a reference term. The last item in the dialog, "Open Declaration in..." is now un-clickable, annihilating my work flow.

Comment: So what do you have to do to see the change?